# Mostrar nombre del id de una tabla asociada Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo una vista donde hay una tabla que me muestra el id de otra tabla referenciada, pero quiero que en vez del id me imprima el nombre del mismo.

Me explico, tengo los campos "Provincia y País" en Provincia me imprime normalmente la que le asigne mediante el controlador donde me traigo el modelo, pero el País me imprime es el ID del país, 1 el cual seria Ecuador, o 2 = Perú, 3 = Bolivia etc.. quiero que en vez del ID me muestre el nombre del País.

Controlador:

```
 public function Provincias(){
    $Country = Country::All();
    $Provinces = Province::All();
    return view('promoter.AdminModules.Provinces')->with('Provinces',$Provinces)->with('Country',$Country);
}
```

Vista:

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><i class="material-icons"></i>ID</th>
          <th><i class="material-icons"></i>Provincias</th>
          <th><i class="material-icons"></i>País</th>
          <th><i class="material-icons"></i>Opciones</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

    <tbody> 
        @foreach($Provinces as $provinces)
          <tr>
            <td>{{$provinces->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$provinces->province_name}}</td>
            <td>{{$provinces->country_id}}</td> 
            <td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
```

en {{$provinces->country_id}} Quiero que me imprima es el nombre de ese pais.

he visto código por allí y debería quedar algo así {{$provinces->country_id->country_name}} lo supongo, pero no estoy muy informado sobre eso.

Modelo Pais:

```
protected $table = 'country';

     protected $fillable = [
    'id', 
    'country_name', 
    ];
```

Modelo Provincia:

```
 protected $table = 'province';

     protected $fillable = [
    'id', 
    'province', 
    ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes definir la relación en el modelo, sería algo así en cada modelo:

País (asumo que el modelo se llama Country):

```
public function provinces()
{
    return $this->hasMany(App\Province::class);
}
```

Provincia (asumo que el modelo se llama Province):

```
public function country()
{
     return $this->belongsTo(App\Country::class);
}
```

Ya en el controlador harías algo así, aunque no entiendo para qué cargas los países y las provincias por aparte:

```
public function Provincias(){
    $countries = Country::all();
    $provinces = Province::with('country')->get();

    return view('promoter.AdminModules.Provinces', compact('countries', 'provinces'));
}
```

Es importante en este caso utilizar Eager Loading para precargar las relaciones en solo una consulta.

Por último, en la vista accedes a la relación como una propiedad dinámica:

```
    @foreach ($provinces as $province)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$province->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$province->province_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$province->country->country_name}}</td> 
      </tr>
    @endforeach
```

---

Tal vez lo más importante de esta respuesta, es revisar la documentación para entender cómo y por qué hacerlo así: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Excelente amigo funciona perfecto, muchísimas gracias!